# Bash: Escaping double quotes in $() command substitution

Tags: bash, quoting, command-substitution

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how command substitution works when part of the command's parameters come from a variable.

To illustrate, I'll just present a series of commands:

I'll first create a directory `A B C` in my tmp directory, in the new directory I'll create a new file `abcfile`:

```
user@desktop /tmp
$ pwd
/tmp

user@desktop /tmp
$ mkdir "A B C"

user@desktop /tmp
$ ls
'A B C'

user@desktop /tmp
$ touch "A B C"/abcfile

user@desktop /tmp
$ ls "A B C"/
abcfile
```

I'll new assign the value `A B C` to a variable `$DIR` and attempt to call `ls` to list the contents of this directory using various ways of calling the command

```
user@desktop /tmp
$ DIR="A B C"
```

With the variable unquoted, the command fails as expected

```
user@desktop /tmp
$ ls $DIR
ls: cannot access 'A': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'B': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'C': No such file or directory
```

With the variable quoted, it works as expected

```
user@desktop /tmp
$ ls "$DIR"
abcfile
```

If I want the output of the command as a string

```
user@desktop /tmp
$ echo $(ls "$DIR")
abcfile
```

This command works, but why does it work? According to shellcheck this is actually not correct, the variable should be outside of double quotes

```
user@desktop /tmp
$ echo "$(ls "$DIR")"
abcfile
```

If the inner variable is not double quoted, the command fails

```
user@desktop /tmp
$ echo "$(ls $DIR)"
ls: cannot access 'A': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'B': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'C': No such file or directory
```

Comment: n.b. that notwithstanding the syntax highlighting here, the only part of `"$(ls "$DIR")"` that *isn't* quoted is `ls`. I don't think the duplicate draws that to the fore, but it helps to understand that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you know that `echo "$(somecommand)"` could just be replaced by `somecommand` as `echo` is not needed for outputting the output of a command, and that you use this construct just as an example.

The command `echo $(ls "$DIR")` "works" because `ls "$DIR"` outputs `abcfile` which `echo` outputs.

Quoting the command substitution here will not make a difference in this case.  The string `abcfile` does not need quoting, unless you change `$IFS` to include characters present in that filename (see why below).

However, consider

```
A B C/
|-- A*
`-- abcfile
```

Now:

```
$ echo "$(ls "$DIR")"
A*
abcfile
```

```
$ echo $(ls "$DIR")
A B C abcfile
```

You will notice that the last output expanded the filename `A*` as a filename globbing pattern, which matches the name of the directory `A B C`.  You will also notice that we lost the newline that `ls` outputted.

The newline was lost because the shell did *word-splitting* on the unquoted output of `ls`, splitting it into words on spaces, tabs and newlines (the default contents of `$IFS`).

The name of the directory `A B C` was inserted because the words generated by the word splitting underwent *filename generation* (globbing).

If the name of the new file had been `A* A*`, the name of he directory would have been inserted twice:

```
A B C/
|-- A* A*
`-- abcfile
```

```
$ echo $(ls "$DIR")
A B C A B C abcfile
```

Related:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

Comment: Hi Kusalananda,

I'm puzzled, is it really possible a filename with a "*" character in it? 

Also, my question is also more with regards to how a variable is expanded within a double quoted string. In the context of a command, having the parameter value double quoted makes a difference (as the command will receive the parameter value as a single value, even if it may have space characters in it).

Comment: @wshyang You can have filenames with `*` in it, yes. You can also have newlines, tabs, and many other "strange" characters in filenames. You can have filenames with any character except for `/` (which is the path separator) and the `\0` character (which is a string terminator in the C language). I don't understand your question about variables in double quoted strings. A variable within a double quoted string will be expanded, and the resulting value will be part of the double quoted string. It is not different if this string is then used by a command.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is the main misunderstanding:

> the variable should be outside of double quotes
>
> ```
> user@desktop /tmp
> $ echo "$(ls "$DIR")"
> abcfile
> ```

The variable is not outside of double quotes. The shell considers quoting inside `$()` **separately** than quoting outside it. This means in `echo "$(ls "$DIR")"` the double-quotes are in fact *nested*:

```
echo "$(ls "$DIR")"
#          ^    ^     inner quotes
#    ^            ^   outer quotes
```

And because in general it's good to double quote variables *and* whole `$()` statements (unless you know you don't want to quote), you need each of these quotes.

Compare "quirk number 2" in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1404245/432690).

---

Side issue:

> If I want the output of the command as a string
>
> ```
> user@desktop /tmp
> $ echo $(ls "$DIR")
> abcfile
> ```

Output to stdout has no type, `echo` doesn't make it a string. In this particular case `echo` changes nothing but please see [*What is wrong with `echo $(stuff)`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)